# Confusion with map() in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was learning React and wanted to use map() function. Here i the code:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = { car:[
    {carTitle:'Toyota'},
    {carTitle: 'Honda'},
    {cartitle: 'Chevrolet'}
  ] };

  render() { 
    return ( <div>
      {this.state.car.map((item, index)=>
      <h1>{item.carTitle}</h1>
      )}
    </div> );
  }
}
```

The question is why if I use

```
{this.state.car.map((item, index)=>
          <h1>{item[index].carTitle}</h1>
```

I get an error. Since I have array of objects, I think it is logical to use `{item[index].carTitle}`. But if I use `<h1>{item.carTitle}</h1>`, all works ok. Why? Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: Since you use are in the function of map, you have one item, not the array.

Comment: Your second example would need to be `{this.state.car[index].carTitle}` to do what you think it does. The ugliness in this line of code should help motivate why the first parameter for the callback is the item itself, saving the pain of indexing that you'd need to do with a traditional loop to access it.

Comment: It may be clearer if you name your variables appropriately. car = cars, item = car. `this.state.cars.map(car => <h1>{car.carTitle}</h1>)`

Comment: What @Nikolaus says is correct. This has nothing to do with React, just how .map works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map Look here for more info.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Map loops over each item in the array (the first argument in the callback) and creates a new array with the result of the operation performed in the callback. React then interprets the resulting array and renders each item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `.map()` you need to pass a function as a callback, like the one you are already passing: `.map( (item, index) => ... )`

The first argument of this callback function, `item`, is the current element that is been processed in the array. `index` is the current position.

`item` already returns the content of each position of the array, in this case each object that you defined in `car`.

So, your second example, `item[index].carTitle`, is incorrect because you are trying to access an array position that doesn't exist inside each object.

Also, everytime you use a `.map()` in ReactJS applications, you need to specify a `key` to the element you are returning inside this function, in this case: `<h1 key={index}>{{car.carTitle}}</h1>`.

**Golden tip**: to make your code clearer and avoid confusion you should rename `car` to `cars`, as it is a list of cars, and instead of using `item` you should use `car`. It will make your code more legible and anybody that reads your code can understand it easier than if you are using generic names. So it would look something like this:

```
cars: [
  {carTitle:'Toyota'},
  {carTitle: 'Honda'},
  {cartitle: 'Chevrolet'}
]
```

and:

```
{this.state.cars.map( (car, index) => {
  <h1 hey={index}>{{car.carTitle}}</h1>
})}
```

Further readings:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
- https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html
- Clean Code, Book by Robert Cecil Martin